# unable to get the dropdown working when placing with the radiobutton

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am extending the radiobuttons by adding a dropdown. The radiobutton has a sliding effect which hides all unselected radio buttons. But when i add the dropdown with the radiobutton the dropdown is not working.

Html

```
<form>
  <group class="inline-radio">
    <div>
      <input id="opt1" type="radio" name="title">
      <label>opt1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="opt2" type="radio" name="title">
      <label>opt2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="opt3" type="radio" name="title">
      <label>opt3</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="opt4" type="radio" name="title">
      <label>opt4</label>
    </div>

                  <!-- DropDown -->
               <div class="dropdown">
                 <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                   Others
                   <span class="caret"></span>
                 </button>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                   <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                 </ul>
               </div>
               <!-- DropDown End-->

  </group>
  <span>Please choose one</span>

</form>
```

javascript

```
//for toggling  
var hid = false;

$("group.inline-radio").click(function() {
  if (hid == false) {

    $('group.inline-radio').find('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').parent().hide().find('label').hide();



    hid = true;
    return;
  } else {
    $('group.inline-radio').find('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').parent().show().find('label').show();

    hid = false;
  }

});


$("input:radio[name=title]").click(function() {

     var   id= $(this).attr('id');
      var value;
  var value;
 $("input:radio[name=title]")
  switch (id) {
    case "opt1":
        value = "opt1";
        break;
    case "opt2":
        value = "opt2";
        break;
    case "opt3":
        value = "opt3";
        break;
    case "opt4":
        value = "opt4";
        break;
    case "opt5":
        value = "opt5";
        break;
    case "opt6":
        value = "opt6";
        break;
    case "opt7":
        value = "opt7";
        break;

      default: 
        value = "Please choose an option";
}
 $( "span" ).text( value );

    });
```

Here is the project in codepen  http://codepen.io/flyingboy007/pen/wKpWoY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I may have found it. Remove the overflow: hidden:

```css
.inline-radio {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 3px;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  border: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
}
```

This brings the dropdown options back for selecting.

Regarding the functionality from here, I would check in the js toggle function for whether it was a radio button or the dropdown's button that was clicked. Adjust accordingly for hiding on a click of a radio button or selecting a list item element.

Also give the output span a class and use it when displaying the tip/message.

```html
<span class="tip">Please choose one</span>
```

And

```js
$("span.tip").text(value);
```

This prevents the message appearing next to the button (there is a span there too).

Comment: Thank you...Thought it was javascript issues and was messing with that..and by the way thanks for pointing the span issue..It came when i added dropdown which has a span aswell and  havent noticed it..:)

Comment: No problem - took a while working out the functionality with it broken. Good luck with the project.

Answer (score 0):

If you move `<div class="dropdown">.....</div>` outside the GROUP tag, dropdown works fine.

DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGXwdE

```
<form>
  <group class="inline-radio">
    <div>
      <input id="opt1" type="radio" name="title">
      <label>opt1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="opt2" type="radio" name="title">
      <label>opt2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="opt3" type="radio" name="title">
      <label>opt3</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="opt4" type="radio" name="title">
      <label>opt4</label>
    </div>
  </group>

  <!-- DropDown -->
  <div class="dropdown">
                 <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                   Others
                   <span class="caret"></span>
                 </button>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                   <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                 </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- DropDown End-->

  <span>Please choose one</span>

</form>
```

Comment: yes it does but i need it along with those radios as the dropdown is extending the radios. For eg,  the options which are not seen in radios are extended to dropdown. when someone selects an option in dropdown all other radiobuttons hide as now and vice versa